Farnsworth fusor and ionized plasma generator?
I had an idea for a fusion reactor similar to a tokamak design. It works in a vacuum and runs similar to a Farnsworth fusor but instead its run through something like an ionized plasma generator. Is this possible? If so, is there a mathematical equation I can use to tweak the variables to prove my idea?
